# Reset password of B2C local account in Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

We want to reset the password of local B2C user accounts through the Azure portal.

After resetting, when trying to log on with the new password an error is shown (Invalid username or password) and the user is unable to log on.

We found info on this issue on [github.com](https://github.com/twright-msft/azure-content/blob/master/articles/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-limitations.md#issues-with-admin-initiated-password-reset-on-the-azure-portal) dated three years ago. The suggested workaround is through https://graph.windows.net but so far we were unsuccesful to get this working.

Comment: Do you read the document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-sspr)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are wanting to reset the password for an account interactively, then you can:

1. Browse to https://graphexplorer.azurewebsites.net/.
2. Log in with a Global Administrator user that is a member of your Azure AD B2C directory.
3. Change the request verb from **GET** to **PATCH**.
4. Change the request URL to `https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/{user_id}`.
5. Enter the following JSON in the request body and then select **Go**:

```
{
  "passwordProfile": {
    "password": "{new_password}",
    "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": false
  }
}
```

If you are otherwise wanting to do it programmatically, then you can refer to [the Azure AD Graph API documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/api-catalog) for [resetting a password for an account](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/users-operations#ResetUserPassword).

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you for looking into our issue.

When trying the interactive method, we get an error back:
{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en",
            "value": "Invalid domain name in the request url."
        }
    }
}

We tried the guid of the B2C tenant and also the domain name, but both gave this error. The request does work for the domain name of our main tenant.

Comment: You might be experiencing this `Request_BadRequest` error if you aren't signed in with an authorized user. Ensure you are signed in with a local user, i.e. not a Microsoft Account or guest user, who is assigned to the Global Administrator role.

Comment: Thanks Chris, this did the trick!
We don't get a response back when sending the PATCH request, the request times out. But the password has changed. So we're saved. Thanks again!